# Can Meteor.js fully substitute traditional PHP/MySQL/Apache stack?

Tags: frameworks, meteor, single-page-application, meteorite

I followed several tutorials and examples in Meteor, but they are always showing what is Meteor goot at. So my question would be, what is Meteor bad at?

Could I for example develop an eshop (which would be a typical task for PHP developer) with ease? Or is Meteor specifically aimed at different kind of websites?

Comment: You could, and it would be much easier than in PHP.

Comment: Hubert, are we talking clean PHP or PHP and frameworks? In my current PHP framework, it is very easy to build forms with complex validation, do image manipulation (including writing text on it) etc. Is all this possible with Meteor? Thanks.

Comment: As someone recently put it, "Meteor will wipe out Rails like the dinosaurs". You don't want to know what it will do to PHP.

Comment: I do, hence the question.

Comment: Meteor is primarily aimed at realtime, thick client, data centric web applications. There is not much that PHP applications can do that would be difficult in a Meteor application. There is A LOT that Meteor can do that is extremely difficult in a PHP application.